# How to add handlers to SavingChanges event before model is created in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, invalidoperationexception

I would like to execute two operations in `OnModelCreating` method of class 
that inherits from the `DbContext` class: one using `DbModelBuilder` instance and other using context for adding handler to `SavingChanges` event. They should be always called together to avoid calling one without another.

Problem is that context cannot be used before model is created, so I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException` exception.

Is there any solution for my problem?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    TwoOperations(modelBuilder);
}

private void TwoOperations(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    FirstOperation(modelBuilder);
    SecondOperation();
}

private void FirstOperation(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Do something with modelBuilder...
}

private void SecondOperation()
{
    (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.SavingChanges += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain better what you are trying to archive. If you want to do something when Saving you should use Interceptors *http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/database-command-interception.aspx*. You can add custom *http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx*

Comment: if secondOperation does not depend on the model, you can call it in context constructor. Otherwise, you should split it up, because SavingChanges (and the context on its own, for that matter) uses the already existing model and therefore cannot be used while building it.